# Using namespaces with C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, namespaces

I'm just starting out learning C# this may be really simple but in VB i have these namespaces

```
<%@ import Namespace="System.Data" %>
<%@ import Namespace="System.Globalization" %>
<%@ import Namespace="System.Data.SqlClient" %>
```

How do I go about using those namespaces in C#?

I tried

```
namespace System.Data
```

and

```
using System.Data
```

but they didn't work

Comment: You need to end the using statement with a ;

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Are you trying to import namespaces into an Asp.net page?  If so the code you listed with a case change will work fine.

```
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Data"%>
```

If you're trying to import them into an actual .cs file then you need the "using" directive

```
using System.Data;
using System.Globalization;
```

Comment: I'm importing them into a `aspx` page - Case change did the trick - Thanks

Comment: Should I be using .cs files instead of .aspx?

Comment: @Jamie for the actual HTML / ASP.Net content ASPX is the right place.  I just mentioned the .cs file because I couldn't tell from the question which file you were having a problem with so I put the solution for both.

Comment: @Jamie Taylor: Yes. Yes you should. Although you are permitted to do so by the ASP.NET framework (mostly in an effort to bring in classic ASP programmers) you should, for maintainability's sake, have *no* actually executable code in your .aspx file. There are always niche reasons to break that rule, but as a general rule, it's an big one.

Comment: @Randolpho so should all my executable code be in a .cs file which i link to from my .aspx file or should my executable code be in a master page?

Comment: @Jamie Taylor: Your executable code should be in the code-behind for whatever control you're writing the code, be it a page (.aspx), user control (.ascx) or a master page (.master). The code should respond to events fired in the [page/control lifecycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx), modifying data in controls defined in the markup file as necessary before being rendered.

Answer (score 0):

```
using System.Data;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
using System.Data;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

public class MyClass {}
```

Answer (score 0):

These:

```
<%@ import Namespace="System.Data" %>
<%@ import Namespace="System.Globalization" %>
<%@ import Namespace="System.Data.SqlClient" %>
```

are ASP.NET page directives.  They'll be the same whether your code-behind files are C# or VB.